# Request Stream Get + Post edited JSON body in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to Node.js and am working on a project and I'd like to use Request to stream from one endpoint to another. My goal is to use Request to get and post an edited JSON body using a pipe stream. I know that when doing so, content-type and content-length will be preserved in the POST headers. However, I would like to apply .forEach to all JSON objects in the body from the first url, and post them to the second url.

I'm not sure about the correct format, and I'd appreciate some clarification.

I know the basic syntax is this:

```
request.get('URL').pipe(request.post('URL'));
```

And so far my best guess is something like this:

```
request('FIRST_URL', function (error, response, body) {
  body = JSON.parse(body);
  body.forEach( function(arg) {
      //return edited body
  });
}).pipe(request.post('SECOND_URL'));
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own transform stream. For example:

```
 var Transform = require('stream').Transform;
 var inherits = require('util').inherits;

 function JSONTransform() {
   Transform.call(this);
   this._bufffer = '';
 }
 inherits(JSONTransform, Transform);
 JSONTransform.prototype._transform = function(chunk, enc, cb) {
   this._buffer += chunk;
   cb();
 });
 JSONTransform.prototype._flush = function(cb) {
   try {
     var result = JSON.parse(this._buffer);
     this._buffer = null;

     // Do whatever transformations
     // ...

     this.push(JSON.stringify(result));
     cb();
   } catch (ex) {
     cb(ex);
   }
 });

 // Then just pipe
 request.get('FIRST_URL')
        .pipe(new JSONTransform())
        .pipe(request.post('SECOND_URL'));
```

One other slightly different solution that may be worth considering would be to use a third-party streaming JSON parser module, which may or may not work for your use case.